# WSO2 Api Manager passing user/password credentials to backend endpoint token generator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

My backend microservices can be accessed after successfull OAuth authentication process which provides in response to the client access token and refresh token. On WSO2 Api Manager, when defining a new REST API, I successfully reached a backend micro service endpoint by setting endpoint security with OAUTH 2.0 and setting/saving token URL endpoint, client-id, client-secret, username and password, plus additional parameter "scope". It works fine!
But I'd need to pass username and password **dinamically** to the token endpoint generator from the invoked API, possibly from the identity of the user registered to the API. Otherwise, tokens would be granted always to the same user credentials persistently saved within the endpoint configuration data, whoever is invoking the API exposed through WSO2 Api Manager. Any clue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK with the default implementation, You can't really achieve this. But you can write a custom Extension like [this](https://github.com/athiththan11/wso2-oauth-mediator) and engage using a [Mediation Extension](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/changing-the-default-mediation-flow-of-api-requests/).

Also on a different note, If you already have an IDP that takes care of token generation, why can't you just use the same token to Authenticate in both APIM layer and in the backend?

Comment: Thanks. About your second suggestion, would I be able to achieve this without any implementation/modification on the backend side? (let's say it is a black box to me...). Thanks again!

Comment: @Cristiano yes, but you should have access to do modifications in the IDP.

Comment: thanks! I assume IDP stands for Identity Provider, correct? I'm trying to understand how WSO Identity Server works. I've installed successfully and it is now working together with the Api Manager. Do you have any article or post from which I can understand how to achieve what you suggested?

Comment: Yeap, IDP is the Identity Provider(e.g.: WSO2 IS, Okta etc.) I couldn't find a document, but will share if I find anything. Basically, both APIM and your BE connect to the same external IDP. You generate a single token and pass it up to the BE. At APIM it will do the validation and when the request comes to the backend the backend can do its validations.

Comment: I'm trying to follow these articles: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/extending-api-manager/saml2-sso/configuring-identity-server-as-idp-for-sso/#configuring-identity-server-as-idp-for-sso and   https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/install-and-setup/setup/sso/configuring-identity-server-as-external-idp-using-oidc/   ... let's see what comes out of it ;-) Thanks!!!